# How do I load given CSV data file from a given path? (Python)

Tags: csv, path

My professor has instructed me to
Load 3d_classification_data_v0.csv data file, from path: '../mlrefined_datasets/superlearn_datasets/'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use csv or pandas package for reading csv file.

```py
import csv

file = open(“csvfile.csv”)

csvreader = csv.reader(file)

header = []
header = next(csvreader)

rows = []
for row in csvreader:
  rows.append(row)
```